# How to avoid space in SQL Server Dynamic Pivoting

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I’m trying to do dynamic pivoting in SQL Server 2008 and get the following error.

Error Message

> Msg 1038, Level 15, State 4, Line 2
>   An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.

** Notes

- `#Temp_DOF2` is coming from a stored procedure and has the same file structure.

My code :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 --- Get a clean File structure before Pivoting --
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Create Table #Temp_DOF
(
    Product_Family      Varchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ,
    Shipment_Date       Date  ,
    Part                Varchar(1000) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ,
    Order_No            Varchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ,
    [Group]         Varchar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ,
    Outstanding_Qty         Int 

)

Insert Into #Temp_DOF

  SELECT 
        Product_Family,Shipment_Date,Part,Order_No,[Group],
        Outstanding_Qty

  From #Temp_DOF2
    ORDER BY Shipment_Date,Order_No,[Group]     

-------------------------------------------------------------------------                   
               -- Pivoting the Table. --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------  

--- Dynamic Pivoting.. Stuff the parameter with Part Valus and do the Pivoting.

DECLARE @Main_columns   AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @PVT_columns  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @DOF_Results    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


Set @Main_columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Part) 
                    from #Temp_DOF 
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'') 

Set @PVT_columns = STUFF((SELECT Distinct ', isnull(' + QUOTENAME(Part) + ', 0) as ' + QUOTENAME(Part)
                     from #Temp_DOF
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')  


Set @DOF_Results = 'Select Product_Family,Shipment_Date,Order_No, 
                     '+ @PVT_columns+ ', "Group"

                 FROM
                (
                  Select Product_Family,Shipment_Date,Order_No,"Group",
                          Part , Outstanding_Qty
                    From #Temp_DOF

             ) AS SrcTable

                 PIVOT

                (
                 SUM(Outstanding_Qty) FOR Part in (' + @Main_columns + ')
                ) AS PvTable  
                  Order By Shipment_Date,Order_No,"Group"'

Exec(@DOF_Results )
```

Comment: In the future, please indent your code by selecting it and pressing Control-K.

Comment: Sure.. I'm sorry. I didn't know.